# Запись не добавляется в базу MYSQL phpmyadmin xampp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Не добавляется  записи из формы в базу данных в mysql XAMPP.Отправляется код без ошибки но phpmyadmin  записей не показывает.
Вот код. Помогите разобратся

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="test";

$db=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname)or die(mysqli_error);

if(isset($_POST['autorization'])){
$username=trim($_POST['username']);
$password=trim($_POST['password']);
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

mysqli_query("SET NAMES'utf8'");
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `mydb`(`username`,`password`) VALUES('$username','$password')");

$reslult=mysqli_query();
if($reslult== true){
    echo "message send";
}
 }
?>
```

Вот и HTML код

```
<form id="form" class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"required/>
<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"   required/>
<button type="submit"  name="autorization">Log-In</button>
</form>
<?php echo $result;?>
```

---

Некоторые изменения я сделал но не помогло  вот код .

```
<?php

$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="test";

$db=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

    printf ("EROR",mysqli_connect_error);
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['autorization'])){
    $user=$_POST['username'];
    $pass=$_POST['password'];

mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO `mydb`(`username`,`password`) VALUES (NULL,'$user','$pass')");
mysqli_prepare("SET NAMES'utf8'");

mysqli_close($db);  
}

?>
```

вот код html

```
<form id="form" class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"required/>

<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"   required/>
<button type="submit"  name="autorization">Log-In</button>
</form>
```

В MYSQL shell показывает вроде все нормально .Но данные не отправляются

Comment: Значит добавьте в свой код вывод ошибок: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php#refsect1-mysqli.error-examples P.S. Переменные ни кто в запросы не вставляет. Читайте про подготовленные выражения: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Спасибо за ответ  добавил  но   никаких ошибок не показывает

Comment: `$reslult=mysqli_query();` это вообще что у вас?

Comment: и замечу у вас в одном месте `$reslult` а в другом `$result`

Comment: в этом варианте как будет правильно  если нетрудно можете описать правильный вариант